# onYoutubeIFrameAPIReady only fired once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, youtube-iframe-api

I have an angularjs application where i want to show some youtube videos in a newsfeed.
I have created a directive to load the player, and my videos load the first time i'm entering a view containing a video. But if i leave the view, and opens i again the video is not loaded.

It seems that the event "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady" is only triggered first time i enter the view.

**The view:**

```
        <div bind-html-compile="newsitem.description"></div>
```

The newsitem.description is raw html send to the application as json.

so it could look like:

```
{'this is a video <youtube videoid="myYoutubeVideoId"></youtube>'}
```

That is also why im using the bind-html-compile directive.

**The directive**

```
.directive('youtube', function($window) {
return {
    restrict: "E",

    scope: {
        videoid: "@"
    },

    template: '<div></div>',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;

        $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            player = new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
                 playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 0,
                    html5: 1,
                    theme: "light",
                    modesbranding: 1,
                    color: "white",
                    iv_load_policy: 3,
                    showinfo: 0,
                    controls: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                },
                videoId: scope.videoid
            });
        };
    }
}})
```

When i console.log from onYoutubeIFrameAPIReady i only get output the first time..
So im thinking that the event is somehow triggered before the function is ready, but i can't realy figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same problem. Reading this article, which I'm assuming you followed since your code is pretty close to the article's code, you just didn't read to the bottom of the article:

http://blog.oxrud.com/posts/creating-youtube-directive/

I found at the bottom an explanation as to why it was happening, and a demo showing the multiple videos working. I have not tried to fix it myself yet, but wanted to answer your question:

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/8lxuN8/

Comment: Confirmed this works. Using a factory I now see all of my videos playing.